# XNA Scale BoundingBox

Tags: c#, xna, bounding-box

I am working on a class for a button.
The idea is that the button calculates the size of the text and then scale itself accordingly.

```
float X = font.MeasureString(text).X;
float Y = font.MeasureString(text).Y;
float x = 1.0f + (X / buttonTexture.Width);
float y = 1.0f + (Y / buttonTexture.Height);
scale = new Vector2(x,y);
```

This code works great.

I am using BoundingBoxes to check the collision. However, how do I take into account the scale poistion when creating the bounding box?

So far I have:

```
BoundingBox buttonBox = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(location, 0), new Vector3(location.X  + buttonTexture.Width, location.Y  + buttonTexture.Height, 0));
```

I've tried multiplying the lower-right point of the boundingbox by the scale:

```
BoundingBox buttonBox = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(location, 0), new Vector3((location.X  + buttonTexture.Width * scale.X), (location.Y  + buttonTexture.Height) * scale.Y, 0));
```

But the collision was occurring miles from the button

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The line `(location.Y  + buttonTexture.Height) * scale.Y` seems strange to me, shouldn't it be `location.Y  + buttonTexture.Height * scale.Y`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. all Works! :D

Answer (score 0):

Transform the boundingbox by your scale:

```
  scaledBounds = new BoundingBox(bounds.Min * Scale, bounds.Max*Scale)
```